# Joining tables with different column name but same value in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite to work with my database

I have two different tables, with key columns that have different names but the same value.

As such:

```
shoes
Identification | Name | Shoe size
1                Bob       10
2                John      12


payment
PaymentID | Price | Year
1            20     2013
2            38     2015
```

I need

```
Identification(or PaymentID, no matter) | Name | Shoe size | Price | Year
1                                          Bob       10        20   2013
2                                          John      12        38   2015
```

I've been searching, and trying to understand the tutorials to no avail. I guess im just too stupid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select s.identification, s.name, s.`shoe size`, p.price, p.year
from shoes s
join payment p on p.paymentid = s.identification
```

Comment: Thank you

This is so basic but it was just the last part of your reply that I had potatoe'd in my brain.